# Django make a custom field name

Tags: django, django-models

I know that I can have `verbose_name` on each model's field like so

```
form_name = models.CharField('Form Name', max_length = 100)
```

How if I want to change a specific field's name just for a specific view/case?

For example, on a certain case I want it to be "Your Form Name", and on another case I want it to be "His Form Name", etc.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: For a specific view? You mean in a form? I think you are mixing up models and forms, which is really a bad idea.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think you are mixing up models and forms. A *model* is used to store and manipulate data. It also implements the *semantical layer* of your *business logic*.

A *form* is used to construct convenient ways for a user to *enter data*. A form can *target* a specific model. But this is *not* per se the case: some forms manipulate different model instances at once, or no models at all, or only parts of a specific model.

A model can be manipulated through *different* forms. For example one form can update a certain subset of a model instance whereas another form can update another subset. The idea is that usually a model has *no* knowledge of the forms that edit the model, whereas the forms that target a model require some knowledge about the model (at least a limited list of fields to edit).

To answer your question, you typically thus define a model like:

```
class SomeModel(models.Model):

    name = models.CharField(max_length = 100, verbose_name='Label 1')
```

Now by default `ModelForm`s will take the `verbose_name` as the label, but you *can* override this. For example we can define two forms that both target `SomeModel`:

```
class SomeModelForm1(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = SomeModel
        fields = ['name']

class SomeModelForm2(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = SomeModel
        fields = ['name']
        labels = {'name': 'Label 2'}
```

The second form will thus use another `label` for the `name` field.

Answer (score 1):

If you using Django Forms you can use what @Wiliem Van Onsem said, if you trying to change it at ListView in django admin you can use short_descriptions

```
def _new_first_name(obj):
    return obj.first_name
upper_case_name.short_description = 'Custom First Name'

class PersonAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = (_new_first_name, first_name)
```